# com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

jsondata:

> [{"product_id":"2","product_title":"test","product_thumbnail":"","product_description":"test","product_place":"","product_user":"1","product_store":"","product_date":"1546875653","product_cost":"","product_off":""},{"product_id":"3","product_title":"test1","product_thumbnail":"","product_description":"test1","product_place":"","product_user":"1","product_store":"","product_date":"1546875653","product_cost":"","product_off":""}]

I get this error:

> Rest response error:: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"product_id":"2","product_title":"test","product_thumbnail":"","product_description":"test","product_place":"","product_user":"1","product_store":"","product_date":"1546875653","product_cost":"","product_off":""},{"product_id":"3","product_title":"test1","product_thumbnail":"","product_description":"test1","product_place":"","product_user":"1","product_store":"","product_date":"1546875653","product_cost":"","product_off":""}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

my android code:

```
_httpHandler.addRequest(Request.Method.GET, "product", null, response -> {
        try {
            Log.e("response is:",response.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject product = response.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));

                productList.add(new Product(
                        product.getString("product_id"),
                        product.getString("product_title"),
                        product.getString("product_thumbnail"),
                        product.getString("product_description"),
                        product.getString("product_place"),
                        product.getString("product_user"),
                        product.getString("product_store"),
                        product.getString("product_date"),
                        product.getString("product_off"),
                        product.getString("product_price")));
            }

            ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, error -> {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Get Product Has Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Rest response error: ", error.toString());
    });
```

and AddRequest function is:

```
public void addRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                       Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    url = api_url + url;
    Log.e("url is: ", url);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);}
```

Can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will help you

Here you need to get your JSONArray from your response

like this

```
try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject product= json.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.e("json 1", product.getString("product_title"));

                productList.add(new Product(
                        product.getString("product_id"),
                        product.getString("product_title"),
                        product.getString("product_thumbnail"),
                        product.getString("product_description"),
                        product.getString("product_place"),
                        product.getString("product_user"),
                        product.getString("product_store"),
                        product.getString("product_date"),
                        product.getString("product_off"),
                        product.getString("product_price")));

            }
        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Let me know if it works for you. or mark it helpful if it works for you.

Comment: No I have another json url that work correct!!!! I think json has problem!?

Comment: it will work for you definatly as per your current response because your response has json Array at the top

Comment: If you have json Object at top then you get json object first and then get json array from your object

Comment: thanks a lot. "json_encode($array)" changed to "json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)", the problem was fixed. Thank you for your guide

Answer (score 1):

You response is `JSONArray` but you are executing `JsonObjectRequest` so your `Response.Listener` is alos expecting `JSONObject`. That's why volley can't cast `JSONArray` to `JSONObject`. Use [JsonArrayRequest](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.java). So that your `Response.Listener` will expect `JSONArray`

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
productList = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(),new TypeToken<ArrayList<Category>>() {
    }.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that you expect in response a JSONArray as result of your HTTP request but you make a JsonObjectRequest which has a JSOnObject parameter in the OnResponse listener

What you have to do is:

- Make a JsonArrayRequest

As so, you will pass a JSONArray to the OnResponse listener as your parameter.

This link is very helpful because it provides an: [android - Volley JSON Array request example](https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2017/02/android-volley-json-array-request.html)

At the end, your AddRequest function should be something like this:

```
public void addRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray jsonRequest,
                   Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
url = api_url + url;
Log.e("url is: ", url);
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener){
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        params.put("Accept", "application/json");
        return params;
    }
};
requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);}
```